# SVN plugin for tracking file size history

Tags: svn, version-control, filesize

I'm looking for a way of seeing the history of a file's size. At some point the file got really bloated and I Want to check at which revision this happened.

Are there any methods/plugins for doing this? And is it possible with other version control systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svnlook has an option to check the size of files in the repository. From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svnlook.c.filesize :

```
$ svnlook filesize -r 40 /var/svn/repos trunk/vendors/deli/soda.txt
23
```

You could run that for past revisions until you see the size increase.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) can help you.